# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, uv_resident_set_memory

Tags: node.js, windows-10

I use node.js (win10 + linux mount)

Error appear every times when node.js compile time (or after complie about before 3min).

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, uv_resident_set_memory

The message after node.js process is hard to kill (bash `killall` is not work, so I killed node process via Windows task manager)

What's the problem? I can not find any answer from Google.

```
internal/process.js:103
    memoryUsage_(memValues);
    ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, uv_resident_set_memory
    at process.memoryUsage (internal/process.js:103:5)
    at ConsoleReporter.checkPeakMemory (/home/naruen/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/lib/node_modules/yarn/lib/cli.js:34148:40)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/home/naruen/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/lib/node_modules/yarn/lib/cli.js:34141:13)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:498:11)
    at Timer.unrefdHandle (timers.js:611:5)
```

Comment: has anyone figured this out yet? I have the same problem in my ubuntu server

Answer (score 1):

This bug has many layers. First of all is the fact that you were running in a Windows Linux Subsystem 1.x container. WSL 1.x containers are all missing some entries in `/proc`. The missing 'files' in `/proc` are not really missing files, but actually just how the linux kernel exposes handles for getting process information.

Secondly, node.js is built on [libuv](https://github.com/libuv/libuv), which relies on `/proc/self/stat` in order to fetch some information about current memory usage (RSS) when the built-in node method `process.memoryUsage` is called.

[libuv source](https://github.com/libuv/libuv/blob/b12699b1efabfd241324f4ab6cfd6ce576db491e/src/unix/linux-core.c#L167) for the relevant call:

```
int uv_resident_set_memory(size_t* rss) {
  char buf[1024];
  const char* s;
  ssize_t n;
  long val;
  int fd;
  int i;

  do
    fd = open("/proc/self/stat", O_RDONLY);
  while (fd == -1 && errno == EINTR);
```

Lastly, `yarn` is attempting to execute `process.memoryUsage()` to monitor memory usage during your build and report it to the CLI. Unfortunately, due to the fact that `/proc/self/stat` is one of the entries missing in WSL 1.x, libuv cannot find the 'file' and the process crashes with this relatively vague error message.

On the bright side, I just checked a docker container running Debian using WSL 2.0 as the docker backend and it seems WSL now correctly exposes `/proc/self/stat`. Just to confirm I ran node in that container and executing `process.memoryUsage()` no longer causes a crash.